# How can I change font type in an histogram legend in R?

Tags: r, histogram, legend

I have used "text.font = 4", but that did not work. Any ideas on how to do this in base R?

Thanks!

Comment: Check `?theme` for `ggplot2`.

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow. Please improve your question in way that it will comply to [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also please check [How to Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When you say you want to change the legend,  do you mean that you just want to change the axis labels or are you using the `legend` function to add a legend? Or perhaps you mean that you want to change the main title?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what part of the text you want to change, so I will just demonstrate how to change the various kinds of text.

You can change the labels on the axis tick marks with `font.axis`

```
hist(iris[,4], font.axis=4)
```

[image: Changed tick marks]

You can change the labels on the axis with `font.lab`

```
hist(iris[,4], font.lab=4)
```

[image: Changed axis labels]

You can change the main title with `font.main`

```
hist(iris[,4], font.main=4)
```

[image: changed main title]

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I am interested in the Legend font type in a histogram. There does not seem to be an obvious way to change the font text type inside the legend of a histogram.